# How to maximize sales using lpSolve with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

Let's say I'm trying to maximize sales and have two variables, the amount spent on two types of advertisements, `ads` and `ads2` in dollars, that affect the `sales`.

After calculating a linear model on the effect of sales I extract the coefficients to get the formula for the predicted sales. Then I try to maximize the predicted sales by optimizing for the amount of ads.

The problem is that there should be also a budget for the types of advertising. Without this constraint all of the advertising budget would be spent on `ads` rather than `ads2`.

This causes the sales to be about 140 dollars, but a little bit of sales could be sacrificed to meet this constraint.

I don't know how to implement this. I tried adjusting the constraints in the const matrix but the optimization tried to force all advertising to only one of the types of ads.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lpSolve)

data <- tribble(~"ads", ~"ads2", ~"sales",
                 100,    120,      100,
                 50,     90,       40,
                 20,     10,       10,
                 150,    110,      130,
                 190,    90,       160,
                 180,    300,     250,
                 110,    200,      100,
                 80,     70,       20,
                 50,     20,       10,
                 30,     100,      200,
                 100,    190,      40,
                 100,    200,     100,
                 40,     90,       80,
                 60,     80,       60,
                 200,    20,       100,
                 20,     200,      80,
                 30,     10,       30,
                 40,     90,       100,
                 80,     20,       80,
                 200,    150,      100,
                 80,     80,       40,
                 100,    10,       300,
                 150,    100,      60,
                 10,     100,      10
)

forecast <- lm(sales ~ ads + ads2, data = data)

coef <- forecast$coefficients

obj <- coef[2:3] # coefficients
const <- matrix(c(1, 1,  # ads
                  1, 1), # ads2
                nrow = 2)

min_items <- 250 # minimum total budget
max_items <- 300 # maximum total budget

rhs <- c(min_items, max_items)

direction  <- c(">", "<")

optimum <-  lp(direction = "max", obj, const, direction,  rhs)

optimum$solution # budget spent on ads and ads2
optimum$objval + coef[1] # forecasted sales by using this budget
```

`optimum$solution` should not be 0 for either of the ad types, it should return for example 50 100 instead of 300 0 or 0 300.

Comment: This is rather unconstructive, but i'd suggest reading the help page for `lpSolve::lp()`. Questions about specific function utility can almost always be answered by using 5 minutes on a help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a new constraint, `max_ads`, and setting it to the maximum value of ads that you want. Also the constraint matrix had to be changed by setting zero to the corresponding constraint for `ads2`. Also the sign for the direction had to be changed.

```
const <- matrix(c(1, 1,  # ads
                  0, 1), # ads2
                nrow = 2)

max_ads <- 100 # maximum ads budget
max_items <- 300 # maximum total budget

rhs <- c(max_ads, max_items)

direction  <- c("<", "<")
```